# Protect Laravel (Vapor) with custom AWS WAF rules

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-waf, laravel-vapor

We would like to protect Laravel site.
Laravel Vapor employs AWS WAF, but configuration is [limited](https://docs.vapor.build/1.0/projects/environments.html#firewall)

What we would like to achieve:

1. Ability to temporarily add an IP address to AWS WAF from Laravel code.

e.g. something throws SuspiciousOperationException and we block that IP for 5 minutes using AWS WAF.
I guess there should be some sort of an API call from PHP to AWS WAF

2. Ability to filter method spoofing via WAF, not allowing to reach PHP code

e.g. we get attempts where $method is replaced by `../etc/passwd`

```
in /var/task/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Request.php (line 1228)
    if (\in_array($method, ['GET', 'HEAD', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'CONNECT', 'OPTIONS', 'PATCH', 'PURGE', 'TRACE'], true)) {
        return $this->method = $method;
    }
    if (!preg_match('/^[A-Z]++$/D', $method)) {
        throw new SuspiciousOperationException(sprintf('Invalid method override "%s".', $method));
    }
```

Is this viable? Cannot find anything related to this subject.